# Request page on hover and iframe type loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a menu of links that I want to preview individually with a window of the page opening on mouse hover.

Having multiple iframes loaded and hidden uses too much cpu.

I want to request the page on hover and terminate the connection/loading on end of hover. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use images instead?  Just a suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr()` method to change the `src` of just one iFrame as needed.

```
var $iFrame=$('#iFrameID');    
$('.someClass').hover(){
    var src= this.href /* not sure of source*/
    $iFrame.show().attr('src', src);
},function(){
   $iFrame.hide()
});
```

I used hide and show for simplicity, you can dynamically add and remove iFrame as well

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/